# Why simple future?

Tags: future-perfect

[image]

I'm super confused why simple future is used in The first and second sentence, not future perfect?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Would you mind copying out the text from the image into your question? Images aren't searchable for text. Also, please tell us what you already know about will-future and future perfect and why you think they should be future perfect, it will help us give you quick and concise answers. [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Being back home is an ongoing state, not an event. That is why we say:

> By the time you receive this postcard, I'll be back home.

You could also say:

> By the time you receive this postcard, I'll have arrived home.

> By the time you receive this postcard, I'll have got back home.

(To get home = to reach home, arrive home)

But if you said:

> By the time you receive this postcard, I'll have been back home

It would imply that you had been home but then left again on a second trip.

> By the time we get there, it will be closed.

While "it will have been closed" would be grammatically correct, it would be an unusual way of saying it. We use "closed", *adjective* here.